# I am getting error in odoo13 I setup new odooo I am try to install new custom modules

Tags: python-3.7, odoo-13

```
odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 592, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Field `invoice_is_snailmail` does not exist

Error context:
View `n/a`
[view_id: n/a, xml_id: n/a, model: n/a, parent_id: n/a]
```

I check in my code invoice_is_snailmail this files written in files but still odoo though an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `invoice_is_snailmail` is a field in standard Odoo module `snailmail_account`. If you want to use this field in your custom module, you need to install snailmail_account module first.

Best practice is to list the dependent module snailmail_account as a dependency in your module so that Odoo will install it automatically. More info on module definition and depends can be found here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/module.html, see manifest field `depends`.

Comment: I reinstall  snailmail_account then it works form me

Answer (score 0):

Check fields define in py and xml in same module or field for xml in child module.